# Eclipse and Tomcat: Unable to start a War project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

My eclipse setup for web project worked before. But all of the sudden it stops working.

Eclipse version Build id: 20100218-1602

It is a very standard setup. I have a servers project setup in eclipse. I have defined an tomcat server in it. I was able to run my web project this way.

Suddenly for some reason today I saw this exception:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
Error loading class [some.company.persistence.dao.hbm.ProductDaoImpl] 
for bean with name 'productDao' defined in class path resource [SomeDB.xml]:  
problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support
/HibernateDaoSupport
```

Based on the message above, can anyone suggest what may be broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the hibernate library is missing from the project's classpath. Figure out which one of the spring jars contains HibernateDaoSupport and add it to your project's classpath.